# How to convert my script from v3 pinescript to v5 pinescript; the convert option isn't in the editor for some reason

Tags: pine-script

[photo of code and the menu where convert usually is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJmp.png)

As you can see there is no option to convert

```
study("DeMarker & RSI", shorttitle="DM & RSI", overlay=false)
per=input(title="DeMarker Period", type=integer, defval=14)
len=input(title="RSI Length", type=integer, defval=14)
//DM
demax=high>high[1] ? high-high[1] : 0
demin=low<low[1] ? low[1]-low : 0
demax_av=sma(demax,per)
demin_av=sma(demin,per)
dmark=demax_av/(demax_av+demin_av)

//RSI
vrsi = rsi(close, len)

//Plot
h1=hline(30)
h2=hline(70)
fill(h1,h2,color=#6495ED)
h3=hline(10)
h4=hline(90)
fill(h1,h3,color=#00FF7F)
fill(h2,h4,color=#DC143C)
plot(dmark*100, title="DM", color=#7FFFD4, transp=20)
plot(vrsi, title="RSI", color=#FF6347, transp=20)
```

I am very new and honestly have no idea where to start, so I haven't tried much.

Answer (score 0):

It is not there because your code is not `v3`. When there is no version identifier, it will be treated as `v1`.

Add `//@version=3` to top of your code and you will have the option to convert it to `v4`.

[image]